# Is this a proper use of "get"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Sara wanted to get her a present.

Does this make sense?
I think it should be "Sara wanted her to get a present." or "Sara wanted to give her a present."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is an example of the proper use of get. **Get** is used as a common substitute for other verbs such as buy, receive, arrive [get here, get there], understand, catch [a ball] and some others that don't come to mind right now.

> Sara wanted to **get** her a present.
>
> means: Sara wanted to **buy her** a present.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proper use of "get."

In this case, "her" is the indirect object and "present" is the direct object of "get."  It means the same thing as "Sarah wanted to get a present for her."

Answer (score 0):

"get" can mean either:

1) "obtain"/"acquire"/"buy"

or

2) "receive"/"be given"

The first meaning is understood from the sentence "Sara wanted to get her a present" (as in, "Sara wanted to buy a present so Sara could give it to her [someone else, not Sara]").

The meaning is ambiguous in the sentence "Sara wanted her to get a present" (it could mean either, "Sara wanted her [someone else] to buy a gift, possibly to give to a third person" or "Sara wanted her [someone else] to receive a gift").

The other sentence you mention, "Sara wanted to give her a present", has almost the same meaning as "Sara wanted to get her a present". This original sentence you asked about is perfectly grammatical and is clearer than "Sara wanted her to get a present" (From whom did Sara want her to get a present? For whom?).